# string which from textbox to double

Tags: visual-c++

I need to find a way for convert to double the string which i get from textbox. I were use "System::Convert::toDouble" but i want to make a function for this.

```
double strtodbl(double dbl, string str)
{
    dbl=System::Convert::ToDouble(str);
    if(!str)
        dbl=0;

    return dbl;
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you are trying to accomplish and why you are attempting to make your own conversion to double method?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to create your own method to convert a String to a Double. Just use the method provided already.

```
Convert.ToDouble(String)
```

This method will return 0 if the input string is null or throw an exception if the input string is not a number in the valid format. For more info see the [MSDN documentation on the method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1hkw6k.aspx).

Comment: i know that way, but i want to know how can i to the other way

Answer (score 1):

```
double strtodbl(string str)
{
    double num ;
    if( Double::TryParse(str,num))
    {
      return dbl;
    } 
    return 0.0d;
}
```

`if(!str)` doesn't make sense. `str` isn't a bool. `Double::TryParse` handles that for you.